# How can I print data from a website which uses Aspose?

Tags: aspose

Not entirely sure how to word this so apologies if it doesn't make sense straight away.

I am on a website which I need to extract all the data from a specific object, it appears to be similar to an online e-book, something you'd see on a university library page etc.

I looked through the HTML and have seen that it uses Aspose:

```
<meta name="generator" content="Aspose.Words for .NET 15.5.0.0">
```

I was wondering if someone could give me advice or point me in the right direction so I can extract all the data from this online e-book into a pdf that I can use offline?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply load the web page into [Aspose.Words for .NET document object model (DOM)](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Aspose.Words+Document+Object+Model):

```
Document doc = new Document("abc.com/somepage.html");
```

Once the web page is loaded into the Document object, you can choose to [extract Selected Content Between Nodes in a Document](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/How+to+Extract+Selected+Content+Between+Nodes+in+a+Document) or [convert the entire web page to PDF format](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Converting+a+Document#ConvertingaDocument-ConvertMicrosoftWorddocumenttoPDF) by using the following  code:

```
Document doc = new Document("abc.com/somepage.html");
doc.Save(MyDir + @"17.6.pdf");
```

Hope, this helps.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Thanks Awais, I will give this a go. 

Sam

Comment: where can I get the Document DLL from?

Comment: You can get latest version of [Aspose.Words for .NET DLL from here](https://downloads.aspose.com/words/net).